# Hiding default incoming call screen doesn't work all the time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on application that receives incoming calls and automatically answers them. I have an activity that runs while a worker thread automatically answers the calls. What I would like to accomplish is to suppress the default incoming call screen and keep my activity in the foreground while it is running.

After some research here, I have figured this can be accomplished by using a **BroadcastReceiver** and calling **BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()** while setting **android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE** broadcast to the highest priority in my manifest.

Unfortunately, this only works %50 of the time. Half the time I am able to answer the call and my activity remains in the foreground and half the time, that is not the case. How can I get this to work every time?

Here is my manifest:

```
   <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // set a flag for worker thread to answer call
        }
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    abortBroadcast();
 }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the abortBroadcast() call in similar code in Android 4.1.2 - what version are you using to test?

Comment: I am using Android 4.0.3. What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast" - difference in code seems to be that you have a sleep - maybe the broadcast is finished by the time you abort it?  Does anything change if you remove the abortBroadcast() call?

Comment: I had put the sleep there based on an answer from another related SO question. Removing abortBroadcast() just allows the default call screen to appear above my app %100 of the time.

Comment: Hm, I get the same error in 4.0.3 (in logs - doesn't crash the app).  Your sleep is probably giving enough of a delay for your activity to come back to the front - on top of the incoming call screen.  I was hoping to completely suppress it from coming up at all, looks like it might not be possible.

Comment: I took a look at my logcat logs and noticed I am getting the same error as you. Does that mean PHONE_STATE broadcasts are un-ordered? That would mean abordBroadcast() should have no effect. That is not the case though as I notice a difference with it in and out.

Comment: That's what it seems to mean to me - not sure why taking it out changes the effect of your app.  I am still looking into this for myself and will update here if I find anything.